# Android Webview: How to retrieve the expiry date from a cookie

Tags: android, webview, cookiemanager

In Android, is there a way we can check if a cookie used by webkit has expired? `CookieManager.getCookie(url)` doesn't have the expiry dates.

Answer (score -1):

Well you have to retrieve the cookie first to a Cookie (
org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie)  object and then use the  "

> isExpired(Date date)

" that returns true if this cookie has expired.

you can also test the date by using

> getExpiryDate()

.

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking about android.webkit.CookieManager.

Comment: How to initialize object for org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie and where to pass the cookie name?

Comment: @GreenHo is right, there is no info in the cookies retrieved with CookieManager.getCookie other than key and value